# What is the purpose of ireport.x and ireport.y property in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Can anyone let me know the purpose of property ireport.x and ireport.y in JasperReports .jrxml files?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer should be accepted

Answer (score 11):

The parameters ***`ireport.x`***, ***`ireport.y`*** and ***`ireport.zoom`*** are determine how to show report's template in `iReport`. Its just a settings for default displaying report in this designer (iReport).

The parameters ***`ireport.x`*** and ***`ireport.y`*** are determine the default position for template (after opening in designer).

The parameter ***`ireport.zoom`*** is determine the default zoom for template (after opening in designer).

Comment: Yes. And they will therefore be completely ignored by JasperReports at runtime. (They're just a convenience for iReport users.)

Comment: Thank Mdahlman Sir. Are you meaning to say, it doesn't any way reflect the change in generating PDF? correct?